# Requesting info out of DISCORD API INVITES

Tags: javascript, json, get, discord, discord.js

I would like to know how can i request this two values from the https://discord.com/api/v8/invites/, getting the first channel's name and the name of the guild.
Cause im looking foward to do so every invite sent in a channel must have a specific word in the guild name it is from and a specific word as first channel, otherwise it will get deleted.
I would appreciate some help since im new to this a docs got me really confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you try using the API, (this example uses [unblock](https://discord.com/api/v8/invites/unblock))

You get this response:

```json
{
    "code": "unblock",
    "guild": {
        "id": "419123358698045453",
        "name": "TitaniumNetwork",
        "splash": "86378b9059a3fe6d7a76d126c3c4b678",
        "banner": "86378b9059a3fe6d7a76d126c3c4b678",
        "description": null,
        "icon": "870e49b4cd8fce8063b7bda48e33aa46",
        "features": ["COMMUNITY", "WELCOME_SCREEN_ENABLED", "VANITY_URL", "ANIMATED_ICON", "BANNER", "PREVIEW_ENABLED", "INVITE_SPLASH", "MEMBER_VERIFICATION_GATE_ENABLED", "NEWS"],
        "verification_level": 4,
        "vanity_url_code": "unblock",
        "welcome_screen": {
            "description": "We are an organization revolving around proxies, armed with a mission for the protection of freedom and privacy rights to be normalized.",
            "welcome_channels": [{
                "channel_id": "738967801460686889",
                "description": "Read the rules.",
                "emoji_id": "709447784536866869",
                "emoji_name": "verif"
            }, {
                "channel_id": "796606512407511060",
                "description": "Join some discussions!",
                "emoji_id": "766746158546026547",
                "emoji_name": "infernal"
            }, {
                "channel_id": "743646448721068092",
                "description": "Talk about tech!",
                "emoji_id": "779561163293196288",
                "emoji_name": "abraded"
            }, {
                "channel_id": "769716455230668820",
                "description": "Be ready for feedback!",
                "emoji_id": "574816517989072897",
                "emoji_name": "TitaniumNetwork"
            }]
        }
    },
    "channel": {
        "id": "738967801460686889",
        "name": "rules",
        "type": 0
    }
}
```

It's a simple matter of parsing the JSON.

Comment: The problem is how could i return that? Can you show me how could i get guild name out of https://discord.com/api/v8/invites/xcunxAsRu5 for example?

Comment: In this case, it would be response.guild.name